# Loading a Symfony parameter in the AppKernel

Tags: symfony, caching, parameters, symfony-http-client

We need to store our cache and log files outside of the project folder structure. I have set up parameters_prod.yml and parameters_dev.yml that will be build by Bamboo on deployment to different servers/environments.

Is there any way that I can access these parameters in the AppKernal so that I can use them in the getCacheDir() function? This would be the easy way of doing things short of parsing them myself or something.

So the final directory structure should look the same as the default Symfony one, with the exception of the cache and logs. The server team has requested that the cache and logs should be under var/tmp and var/logs. So for an application, the cache would be /var/tmp/symfony/projectName/prod and /var/tmp/symfony/projectName/dev. Logs would follow a similar structure.

So basically the structure would follow the normal Symfony one except /var/www/Symfony/projectName/var/cache becomes /var/tmp/symfony/projectName and /var/www/Symfony/projectName/var/logs becomes /var/logs/symfony/projectName. Note that all these locations here are absolute (and the location of the root of the project may differ slightly, when Bamboo deploys, it will set up the correct paths etc).

One of the strange things is that when I set it up like this, the site actually runs, but I can not see anything under the new cache location (have not started working on the logs side yet). So there has to be cache files somewhere, but a locate doesn't even find them!

NOTE: I have now found that if you run the internal server, this problem doesn't happen. This only happens if you are loading the site under Apache.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your idea is that a service container and parameters are initialized just moment after the ConfigCache object has been constructed, with a absolute cache path as parameter.

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpKernel;

...


/**
 * The Kernel is the heart of the Symfony system.
 *
 * It manages an environment made of bundles.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
abstract class Kernel implements KernelInterface, TerminableInterface
{
    ...
        /**
     * Initializes the service container.
     *
     * The cached version of the service container is used when fresh, otherwise the
     * container is built.
     */
    protected function initializeContainer()
    {
        $class = $this->getContainerClass();
        // !!!!!! cache config object construction
        $cache = new ConfigCache($this->getCacheDir().'/'.$class.'.php', $this->debug);
        $fresh = true;
        if (!$cache->isFresh()) {
            $container = $this->buildContainer();
            $container->compile();
            $this->dumpContainer($cache, $container, $class, $this->getContainerBaseClass());

            $fresh = false;
        }

        require_once $cache->getPath();

        $this->container = new $class();
        $this->container->set('kernel', $this);

        if (!$fresh && $this->container->has('cache_warmer')) {
            $this->container->get('cache_warmer')->warmUp($this->container->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir'));
        }
    }
}
```

So, you can't have access to your custom defined parameters in a getCacheDir() method.

Could you override the getCacheDir() method?

Let's say that your directory structure looks like this

```
-home

 --symfony_app

 --custom_cache_directory
```

Than method override would look something like this:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/../custom_cache_directory/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}
```

More info at official docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-cache-directory

Comment: This is the method I have been playing with, only I am trying to get away from using dirname(\_\_DIR\_\_) as the dir may not be relative to the app dir. I am now getting it to use: /var/tmp/symfony/appname/branchname/dev for example. When I do this the app loads, but I don't know where the cache is, I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: Could you please post me your whole directory structure - you app, your dev cache, your prod cache...

Comment: hmmm... maybe there is a problem with some kind of write permissions for the /var/tmp directory? could you check it with your server team?

Comment: I did, there shouldn't be. Something weird is happening with that dir and Symfony. I added another answer below to show this. We can never see the cache get written even though the page loads fine! I have up-voted your answer as it is correct for normal cases and then added my answer to show more info about using anything under /var/tmp/ Note that this seems to happen on any RHEL install (I tried in my virtual box as well).

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is to do as Matko suggested, and DON'T use the /var/tmp directory.

So in /appName/app/AppKernel.php I edited the getCacheDir() to make it look more like:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return '/var/symfony/cache/projectName' . '/' . $this->getEnvironment();
}
```

or whatever path you want to use.

Don't use anything under /tmp or /var/tmp (I'm on RHEL) as these folders do some weird things (/var/tmp seemed to never actually write the cache to disk).